# Unstable connections

Tags: javascript, webrtc, django-channels

My backend in Python with Django Channel. In it I have a method that selects an online user and sends the data to another user.

But when I'm going to make the connection flow, something is wrong and unstable. Sometimes it works perfect and makes the connection, sometimes bug.

It seems that the sending of "ICE Candidate" enters the front of everything, randomly, causing error. Sometimes it is called only after the response.

Is this initial sequence correct from my WebRTC in Javascript? (OnIceCandidate is shot all the time)

```
function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    window.localStream = localStream = stream;
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

    var iceServers = {
        'iceServers': [
            {'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
            {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
        ]
    };


    //creating our RTCPeerConnection object

    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
    console.log("RTCPeerConnection object was created");
    console.log(peerConnection);


    peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

    if ('ontrack' in peerConnection) {
        // WebRTC Spec, Firefox
        peerConnection.ontrack = function (event) {
          remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
         };
     } else {
        // Chrome, etc. This can be removed once all browsers support `ontrack`
        peerConnection.onaddstream = function (event) {
          // remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
          remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
        };
     }

    //setup ice handling
    //when the browser finds an ice candidate we send it to another peer
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {

       if (event.candidate) {
          send("candidate", {candidate: event.candidate});
       }
    };

    peerConnection.ondatachannel = function(event) {
       var receiveChannel = event.channel;
       receiveChannel.onmessage = function(event) {
          console.log("ondatachannel message:", event.data);
       };
    };
    openDataChannel();
}
```

---

1. **When you do not connect ...**

**LOG - User 1**

```
Websocket Connected
RTCPeerConnection object was created
Send: Notices that it is available...
Received: Found peer
Send: offer
Send: candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: answer
Received: candidate
```

**LOG - User 2**

```
   Websocket Connected
   RTCPeerConnection object was created
   Send: Notices that it is available...
   Received: candidate
   Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
   Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
   Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
   Received: offer
   Send: answer
   Received: candidate
   Send: candidate
   Received:  candidate
   Send: candidate
   Received: candidate
   Send: candidate
   Received: candidate
```

---

1. **When you do CONNECTED ...**

**LOG - User 1**

```
Websocket Connected
RTCPeerConnection object was created
Send: Notices that it is available...
Received: Found peer
Send: offer
Send: candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: answer
Received: candidate
```

**LOG - User 2**

```
Websocket Connected
RTCPeerConnection object was created
Send: Notices that it is available...
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: candidate
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
Received: offer
Send: answer
Send: candidate
Received: candidate
Send: candidate
Received: candidate
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [javascript], [webrtc] and [rtc]?  I don't see any javascript here, but I'm not familiar enough with django, etc. to arbitrarily remove the tag.  Unless there is some javascript hidden somewhere in your question, please remove the tag.   Likewise for [webrtc], and [rtc], And it wouldn't hurt to tag it [Python] Thanks.  (note when you mis-tag a question you waste a lot of people's time)

Comment: @DaleWilson I updated with my JavaScript code for WebRTC.

Comment: Thanks, Luis, but I still wonder does the Javascript matter -- is it relevant to the problem of maintaining a connection that was established in Python?

Comment: I commented on Python an end to explain how I select the pair. All logic is front-end.